# Python packing keyword arguments with *

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I have a code I'm studying and I and completely stuck here.

the code is:

```
def f(*a):
    print a
print (*[1,2]) # prints (1,2)
```

WHY? I don't know the process behind this. I know that the `*args` make variable length arguments into tuples, but what does that `(*[1,2])` perform?

Comment: Are you missing a function call in the last line? Your code won't run as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wanted to write this instead:

```
print f(*[ 1, 2]) # Python 2
print(f(*[ 1, 2])) # Python 3
```

What the `*` does, is something called [**unpacking**](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). In this case, where you are *unpacking* a list. It's usually used to pass a list as "independent" parameters to a function, for example:

```
def f(a, b):
    print a
    print b
```

You can call it like

```
f(*[1, 2])  # with unpacking
```

which is equivalent to

```
f(1, 2)
```

Comment: but doesn't unzipping happens only if you call zip(*Stuff)? Does the * itself also perform that? Or is unzipping a different concept to unpacking?

Comment: Totally different. Just play with it and you will figure out why. Note that when you do `zip(*stuff)` you are first unpacking and the zipping. Each process is different.

Answer (score 0):

This is called argument unpacking - see the reference [at the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

In short, `print f(*[1,2])` takes each element of the list, and passes it as an individual argument to the method `f`.

The method `f` takes a multiple number of positional arguments, which are assigned the name `a` in the body.

So, when you type `f(*[1,2])`, this is the same as `f(1,2)`. On the other side, `f` receives `1,2` as the tuple `a` and prints it:

```
>>> def f(*a):
...    print(a)
...
>>> f(*[1,2])
(1, 2)
```